XCode 16 - some changes to @Observable class not triggering redraw after "upgrade" to XCode 16
I have an application that draws shapes to the screen. The user can drag them around the screen. It works correctly when built using XCode 15 / Swift 5.x. But when it's built using XCode 16 / Swift 6, changes to the data model don't always trigger a redraw.
The data model contains an @Observable class that contains an array of "gadgets", each of which is a struct that contains the screen location where it should be drawn:
@Observable class GadgetModel: Encodable, Identifiable {
    var gadgets  = [GadgetNode]()

Each GadgetNode is a struct:
struct GadgetNode : Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    public var gadgetType: GadgetType = .unassigned
    public var id: Int = 0             
    var location: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)

Each of the GadgetNodes in the data model is drawn by a View that lets the user drag it to a new location. Here's a highly simplified sketch of the view:
struct NodeView<Content: View>: View {
    @Environment(GadgetModel.self) private var gadgetModel
    
    @State   var gadget: GadgetNode
    
    @GestureState private var gadgetDragGestureState: CGOffset = .zero
    
    init(gadget: GadgetNode) {
        self.gadget = gadget
    }
    
    var body: some View  {
        ZStack{
            IconBackground(gadget: gadget, drawImage: gadgetModel.redrawGadgets > 0 )
        }   // ZStack
        .frame(width: NodeConstants.nodeWidth, height: NodeConstants.nodeHeight)
        .offset(gadgetDragGestureState)        // Updates view while drgging
        .gesture(gadgetDragGesture)           // sets self.position    }
    
    
    // drag the node
    var gadgetDragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 3)
            .updating($gadgetDragGestureState) {
                (inMotionDragGestureValue, state, _ ) in
                state = inMotionDragGestureValue.translation
            }
             .onEnded { endingDragGestureValue in                    
                let endLocation = gadgetModel.gadgets[gadget.id].location + endingDragGestureValue.translation
                gadget.location = endLocation
                gadgetModel.gadgets[gadget.id].location = endLocation
                 print("drag has ended. GestureDrag = \(gadgetDragGestureState), final position = \(endLocation)")
                 for gadget in gadgetModel.gadgets {
                     print("Gadget \(gadget.id) location = \(gadget.location)")
                 }
            }
    }

This all appears to still work correctly - while the user is dragging the shape, the shape follows the drag correctly, and the data model is updated correctly. So far, so good.
There's an enclosing view that draws all of the shapes, and that's where things get weird. If the shapes are dragged around the screen, they snap back to their original location. However, if the user adds a new shape, all of the shapes are drawn correctly in the correct locations (again, this was fine with Xcode 15).
The enclosing view also looks at the data model:
struct GadgetDocumentView: View {
    @Environment(GadgetModel.self) private var gadgetModel

There's a ViewBuilder function that returns the various shapes, and each of them are drawn to the screen:
               ForEach(gadgetModel.gadgets) { gadget in
                    getGadgetView(gadget)       // returns a @Viewbuilder view
                      .zIndex(Double(gadget.id))
                        .position(gadget.location)

My apologies for not creating a minimum executable version of this yet - my hope is that someone who understands @Observable behaviour and @ViewBuilder behaviour better than I do will instantly recognize the problem (I'm presumably doing something silly - perhaps something like making the individual shapes handle drag events, instead of doing handling them in the enclosing view?).
Any thoughts?

It's a SwiftUI bug - over-optimization caused the data model change to be ignored.
I replaced:
                   ForEach(gadgetModel.gadgets) { gadget in
                        getGadgetView(gadget)       // returns a @Viewbuilder view
                          .zIndex(Double(gadget.id))
                          .position(gadget.location)

with
               ForEach(gadgetModel.gadgets) { gadget in
                    getGadgetView(gadget)       // returns a @Viewbuilder view
                      .zIndex(Double(gadget.id))
                      .position(gadgetModel.gadgets[gadget.id].location)

